# ruby 1.9 and 1.8.7 installed how do I make app use 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macports

I have two version of ruby installed 1.9 and 1.8.7(via macports) how do I make my app run with 1.8.7?

And How can i uninstall 1.9?

TIA

Comment: The de-facto ruby update mechanism is RVM these days, you can easily install and manage ruby versions

Comment: This is not off-topic. Questions about installation of programming languages are common on SO. And, asking how to get an app to run with a particular version of the programming language is within the scope of the site also.

Comment: There are many related questions on SO over on the right-side of the page. I'd recommend reading "[How does MacPorts install packages? How can I activate a Ruby installation done via MacPorts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333569/how-does-macports-install-packages-how-can-i-activate-a-ruby-installation-done-v)".

Comment: Also, I'd recommend keeping 1.9. Hopefully it's 1.9.2, which has bug fixes and runs faster than 1.8.7 for most things, has Unicode support, and, in general is what you should be using for future compatibility since 1.8.7 is in maintenance now.

Comment: Should the "ruby-on-rails" tag be removed?

Comment: "Should the "ruby-on-rails" tag be removed?". Probably. Nothing in the question specifically applies to Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly: switch to [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) it's excellent for ruby management

If you don't want to then I believe you can remove the ruby package with (if installed with macports) with the following:

```
sudo port uninstall ruby19
```

To start using the new version of ruby you need to find where it is installed (it's something like /opt/local/<...>)

Then go to the Binary folder and add it to path.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/<...>:$PATH
```

Removing the old one, you might need to change some env variables as well.

Use RVM

EDIT: added sudo to port command and changed standard location

Comment: Package managers for Mac OS favor using `/opt/local`, and need `sudo`

Comment: Tried 3 times to install rvm and fails rvnm-install gives me command not found

Comment: If you got no errors during installation it should be in there, firstly the command is rvm install 1.x.x, if you have it set up correctly you can type rvm and it gives usage. If you are using the correct command then you might have forgot to put this [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" at the bottom of your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc assuming you are installing rvm in home folder. Then restart your terminal and try again. The above command points your terminal at the location of the rvm bin (you can check it is in the given path to make sure)

Comment: @jgervin, "rvnm-install gives me command not found" - that's because the command is `rvm install`. Try something like `rvm install 1.8.7` or `rvm install 1.9.2`.